# What happen if a static library (.a) contains duplicated object files (.o)?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, linker

AFAIK, older version of Xcode failed to link a static library if it has been linked multiple times. I think there's a kind of duplicated object-file or symbol issue.

Recently, I realized Xcode5 is not reporting related error anymore on duplicated link of a static library. Here's my test.

---

- I wrote 3 Objective-C classes are named as `s1, s2, s3` in separated projects.
- Each of them is compiled into `s1.o, s2.o, s3.o`,
- and finally archived into `s1.a, s2.a, s3.a`.
- `s2` linked (merged) with `s1`, and `s3` is linked (merged) with `s2` and `s1`.

Finally I got these `.a` files.

```
Eonil$ ar -tv libs1.a  
rw-r--r--     501/20           64 Aug  3 18:38 2014 __.SYMDEF SORTED
rw-r--r--     501/20         5528 Aug  3 18:38 2014 s1.o

Eonil$ ar -tv libs2.a  
rw-r--r--     501/20          120 Aug  3 18:38 2014 __.SYMDEF SORTED
rw-r--r--     501/20         5872 Aug  3 18:38 2014 s2.o
rw-r--r--     501/20         5528 Aug  3 18:38 2014 s1.o

Eonil$ ar -tv libs3.a  
rw-r--r--     501/20          224 Aug  3 18:38 2014 __.SYMDEF
rw-r--r--     501/20         5872 Aug  3 18:38 2014 s3.o
rw-r--r--     501/20         5528 Aug  3 18:38 2014 s1.o
rw-r--r--     501/20         5872 Aug  3 18:38 2014 s2.o
rw-r--r--     501/20         5528 Aug  3 18:38 2014 s1.o
```

Those same named `.o` files are all duplicated.

I wrote a `p1` project which is a command line executable, and linked it with all the `s1.a, s2.a, s3.a`. I expected some duplication error, but it just built and working well!

---

What's happening in Xcode for these duplicated linking of static libraries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Confirmed; the linker stops looking for symbols once it finds it in the first library.

If you use the `-all_load` option, however it will fail:

```
$ clang -all_load -o prog main.o -L. -lone -ltwo -lthree
duplicate symbol _func in:
    ./libone.a(file.o)
    ./libtwo.a(file.o)
duplicate symbol _func in:
    ./libone.a(file.o)
    ./libthree.a(file.o)
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This was tested using C, not that that matters:

```
$ cat main.c
extern void func();

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    func();
    return 0;
}

$ cat file.c
#include <stdio.h>

void func()
{
    printf("func()\n");
}
```